# How can i make many-to-many selected fields clickable as links in django admin panel

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm working on a Django project, and I have an admin panel where I manage projects. In this project admin, I have a **matched_pros** field, which is a **ManyToManyField** related to the "main.User" model. I would like to make the selected fields in the **matched_pros** widget clickable, so that when I click on a user, it takes me to the user change page in the admin panel.

```
matched_pros = models.ManyToManyField(
        "main.User", blank=True, related_name="matched_projects"
    )
```

[exemple: many to many widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8KAy.png)
like in the picture when i click on client alger- c51 block it will take me to admin/main/pro/51/change

I've attempted to add JavaScript code to make the users clickable, but I'm encountering issues with the code not functioning as expected, and i don't wanna complicate it using javascript and adding another file to the codebase